# Can CiviRules Field Value Comparison be made to work with a checkbox field?

Tags: civirules, fieldvaluecomparison

I'm trying to set up a CiviRule using a Field Value Comparison to a checkbox field (i.e. a field that allows multiple values), in this case Preferred Communication Method. It doesn't seem that any of the comparison options (equals, is one of, even regex) work and I suspect that's just because it hasn't been implemented. It looks to me like Field Value Comparison assumes the field has only one value - but I could be wrong.

Has anyone got something like this working?

Comment: In this case, I've solved my particular problem using a smart group based on Preferred Communication Method, but it would be interesting to know the answer to this in general.

Comment: I think the answer is we need API4 CONTAINS to do this (and NOT CONTAINS, which doesn't exist yet), but CiviRules is all API3, so would require some work to make this possible.